# Shopify Storefront API: Getting metafields from page or collection

Tags: collections, graphql, shopify, graphiql

I'm trying to get metafields from pages and collections through the Shopify Storefront API and GraphQL.

However, it seems like it's not possible. Looking through the 'queryable objects'-pages, 'metafields' isn't listed as a field on pages or collections. As seen in this screenshot, GraphiQL also says that it doesn't exist. I've copied the code straight from a part where I get metafields form products.

Can this really be? It seems so odd to me that it should be impossible to get those metafields, but I just can't find a way.

All I want is to be able to get some different portions of text for the website, from a specific collection or page.

[image: Image of problem getting metafields from collection in Shopify Storefront API]

Answer (score 0):

The Storefront API supports metafields for the Product and ProductVariant objects only.

You can refer their documentation here: https://shopify.dev/docs/storefront-api/reference/object/metafield

---

A better approach is to create a custom collection layout where you output the metafields with liquid.

Example:

You create a new collection layout:`collection.meta.liquid`

With the following code in it:

```
{%- layout none -%}
{{- collection.metafields.namespace | json -}}
```

---

`collection.liquid`

Inside the collection ( or you can use a different file, but you need to know the collection url in order to add the `view=` argument at the end ):

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
  fetch('{{collection.url}}?view=meta')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => console.log(res))
</script>
```

And you will get the metafields with that specific namespace.